# Debian 8 Jessie - Postfix + Dovecot, send but not receive mails

Tags: debian, email, postfix, dovecot, imap

I'm setting up a mail server (with Postfix, Dovecot and Postfixadmin) for a non-profit organization that I'm currently building.

I'm able to send but not receive mails over TLS. When sending an email from mail1@mydomain.org to mail2@mydomain.org, it works perfectly.

**POSTFIX**

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-mail.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-mail.key
# smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
smtpd_tls_CApath = /etc/postfix/certs
smtpd_use_tls = yes
# smtpd_tls_req_ccert = yes
smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = yes
tls_ssl_options = NO_COMPRESSION
tls_high_cipherlist = EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:+CAMELLIA256:+AES256:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:+SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!ECDSA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA
smtpd_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, eNULL, EXPORT, DES, RC4, MD5, PSK, aECDH, EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA, EDH-RSA-DES-CDC3-SHA, KRB5-DE5, CBC3-SHA
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers= high
tls_preempt_cipherlist = yes
smtpd_tls_eecdh_grade = strong
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_tls_dh512_param_file = ${config_directory}/dh512.pem
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = ${config_directory}/dh2048.pem

#SMTP
smtp_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-mail.pem
smtp_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-mail.key
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

# smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = imap.mydomain.org
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = imap.mydomain.org, ns339435.ip-xx-xxx-xxx.eu, localhost.ip-xx-xxx-xxx.eu, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf

smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1

# Anti-SPAM rules
# smtpd_recipient_restrictions =  permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
# smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated

# Header checks
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

**dovecot -n**

```
# 2.2.13: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 x86_64  ext4
auth_mechanisms = plain login
mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n/Maildir
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date ihave
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
plugin {
  sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_dir = ~/sieve
}
protocols = " imap sieve pop3"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    address = *
    port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    address = *
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
  service_count = 1
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/ssl-mail.pem
ssl_cipher_list = EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:+CAMELLIA256:+AES256:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!ECDSA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/ssl-mail.key
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = yes
ssl_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3 !TLSv1
userdb {
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/vmail/%d/%n
  driver = static
}
protocol lda {
  mail_plugins = " sieve"
}
protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = 
}
```

When running `tail -f /var/log/mail.log` (after retarting Postfix and Dovecot), I get:

```
Jul 13 14:57:28 ns339435 postfix/master[31748]: terminating on signal 15
Jul 13 14:57:29 ns339435 postfix/master[32671]: daemon started -- version 2.11.3, configuration /etc/postfix
Jul 13 14:57:37 ns339435 dovecot: master: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=32716 uid=0 code=kill)
Jul 13 14:57:37 ns339435 dovecot: imap: Server shutting down. in=679 out=2340
Jul 13 14:57:37 ns339435 dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.2.13 starting up for imap, sieve, pop3 (core dumps disabled)
Jul 13 14:59:21 ns339435 postfix/master[32671]: terminating on signal 15
Jul 13 14:59:22 ns339435 postfix/master[739]: daemon started -- version 2.11.3, configuration /etc/postfix
Jul 13 14:59:38 ns339435 dovecot: master: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=785 uid=0 code=kill)
Jul 13 14:59:38 ns339435 dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.2.13 starting up for imap, sieve, pop3 (core dumps disabled)
Jul 13 14:59:52 ns339435 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<webmaster@mydomain.org>, method=PLAIN, rip=xx.xxx.xx.xxx, lip=xx.xxx.xxx.xxx, mpid=838, TLS, session=<nucsTMEawwBNxVG2>
```

**EDIT: /etc/postfix/master.cf**

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#smtpd     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o content_filter=spamassassin
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING

smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}

dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}

spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
  user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
```

**Here's the mail account configuration I use :**

**IMAPS**

```
Server: imap.mydomain.org
Port: 993
User: mail@mydomain.org
Security: SSL/TLS
Authentification: Password
```

**SMTP**

```
Server: imap.mydomain.org
Port: 465
User: mail@mydomain.org
Security: SSL/TLS
Authentification: Password
```

Thank you. :)

Comment: You forgot to explain what happens when you try to send mail to this domain.

Comment: Just updated my question, thank you. When sending an email from mail1@mydomain.org to mail2@mydomain.org, it works.

Comment: The logs do not show any errors. Please show other parts with delivery failures or whatever you observe. Also, please post `/etc/postfix/master.cf`.

Comment: Just updated my question with the content of the following file: `/etc/postfix/master.cf`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

I uncommented the following line:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

I can now send and receive emails over TLS with the following configuration:

**IMAPS**

```
Server: imap.mydomain.org
Port: 993
User: mail@mydomain.org
Security: SSL/TLS
Authentification: Password
```

**SMTP**

```
Server: imap.mydomain.org
Port: 465
User: mail@mydomain.org
Security: SSL/TLS
Authentification: Password
```